# vscode loopback typescript: problems with intellisense

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, intellisense, loopback

I am building a rest api using loopback.js I recenntly discovered this [npm resource](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/loopback). So I went ahead and installed these types in my project.

But either I am missing something or these types have problems. My intellisense does not show me **everything**. Let me illustrate with an example.

First here is a sample definition of the `PersistedModel` from the `index.d.ts`:

```
class PersistedModel extends Model {

     static count(where?: any, callback?: (err: Error, count: number) => void): void;

     static find(
                  filter?: {fields?: string|any|any[]; 
                  include?: string|any|any[]; limit?: number; order?: string; 
                  skip?: number; where?: any; },
                  callback?: (err: Error, models: any[]) => void): void;    
}
```

Now let say I define a variable `myModel` of type `PersistedModel`

```
var myModel:PersistedModel = some_value;
```

(some_value is also of type PersistedModel)

When I write **`myModel.`**, I would expect visual studio code to display the available list of all methods and properties of PersistedModel

Instead there are some methods although clearly defined in the `index.d.ts` file which do not appear in the dropdown list from intellisense. In the above example, **the find method is missing from the intellisense dropdown list**

Is this a bug in vscode? a poorly generated typings from the loopback or am I doing something wrong with my setup (typescript, vscode).

Has any body being able to write loopback application with typescript? Is there any documentation with best practices?

Thank you for your attention and your help

Answer (score 1):

The methods that do not appear in the dropdown are marked as `static`. The `myModel` variable you have is an instance of `PersistedModel` so it will list only instance methods. If you want to access the static methods use the class reference `PersistedModel.find` instead of the instance variable `myModel`.